# how to find out the multiple counts of specific status in the same table

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g

I have Orders and OrderSubscription tables.the relation between the tables is one-many. I want to find out those orders where one of the OrderSubscription status must be 'Active' and 'Cancelled' and should have more than 1 'Pending' status .

So final result should be come as order id =2 records.

written the below query and its workig fine.Or Is there any other better way to filter the records?

```
select o.id,
       o.order_number,
       o.order_status
  from Orders o
 
 where o.order_status = 'Active' AND
   1=(select count(*) from OrderSubscription where order_id = o.id and subs_status='Active')
    AND
   1=( select count(*) from OrderSubscription where  order_id = o.id and subs_status='Cancelled')
   AND
   1 < (select count(*) from OrderSubscription where  order_id = o.id and subs_status='Pending')
 group by o.id,
          o.order_number,
          o.order_status
 order by o.id;
 
 
 
 

Create Table Orders(id number(5),order_number number(12),order_status varchar2(20));

insert into Orders Values (1,12345,'Active');
insert into Orders Values (2,5757575,'Active');
insert into Orders Values (3,979797979,'Active');
insert into Orders Values (4,3131313133,'Active');

Create Table OrderSubscription(id number(5),order_id number(5),subs_name varchar2(20),subs_status varchar2(20));

insert into OrderSubscription Values(1,1,'360 fhf','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (2,1,'720 cef','Active');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (3,1,'540 abc','Cancelled');


insert into OrderSubscription Values (1,2,'360 fhf','Active');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (2,2,'720 cef','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (3,2,'540 abc','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (4,2,'adada abc','Cancelled');


insert into OrderSubscription Values (1,3,'720 cef','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (2,3,'60 ert','Active');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (3,3,'60 ert','Cancelled');

insert into OrderSubscription Values (1,4,'360 fhf','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (2,4,'560 fhf','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (3,4,'560 fhf','Active');
```

Comment: This looks like Oracle, why is it also tagged with SQL Server?

Comment: I have written in oracle but in real this should work in sql server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to use a  conditional aggregation approach.  One correct way to do this is to aggregate by order number and then assert the various status counts.

```
SELECT o.order_number
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderSubscription os
    ON os.order_id = o.id
WHERE
    o.order_status = 'Active'
GROUP BY
    o.order_number
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN os.subs_status = 'Active'    THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN os.subs_status = 'Cancelled' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN os.subs_status = 'Pending'   THEN 1 END) > 1;
```